# Windows Phone 7 Mango saving the state of a CookieContainer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cookiecontainer

update1: After more research I'm not sure this is possible, [I created a UserVoice entry on fixing it](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/2278081-allow-cookiecontainer-to-be-serialized-deserialize?ref=title).

I'm trying to save CookieContainer on app exit or when Tombstoning happens but I've run into some problems.

[I've tried to save CookieContainer in the AppSettings but when loaded, the cookies are gone](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/67659/413251.aspx).

```
Researching this internally, DataContractSerializer cannot serialize cookies.
This seems to be a behavior that Windows Phone inherited from Silverlight's DataContractSerializer.
```

After doing more research it seemed like the work around was to grab the cookies from the container and save them another way.  That worked fine until I hit another snag.  I'm unable to GetCookies with a Uri of .mydomain.com.  I belive it's because of [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/478521/cookiecontainer-domain-handling-issue). I can see the cookie, .mydomain.com in the domaintable but GetCookies doesn't work on that particular cookie.

[The bug is posted again here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/260235-Bug-in-CookieContainer-where-do-I-report).

> There is also a problem with getting cookies out of a container too
>   when the domain begins with a .:

```
CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
container.Add(new Cookie("x", "1", "/", ".blah.com"));
CookieCollection cv = container.GetCookies(new Uri("http://blah.com"));
cv = container.GetCookies(new Uri("http://w.blah.com"));
```

I found a work around for that using reflection to iterate the domaintable and remove the '.' prefix.

```
private void BugFix_CookieDomain(CookieContainer cookieContainer)
{
    System.Type _ContainerType = typeof(CookieContainer);
    var = _ContainerType.InvokeMember("m_domainTable",
                               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField |
                               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance,
                               null,
                               cookieContainer,
                               new object[] { });
    ArrayList keys = new ArrayList(table.Keys);
    foreach (string keyObj in keys)
    {
        string key = (keyObj as string);
        if (key[0] == '.')
        {
            string newKey = key.Remove(0, 1);
            table[newKey] = table[keyObj];
        }
    }
}
```

Only, when InvokeMember is called a MethodAccessException is thrown in SL.  This doesn't really solve my problem as one of the cookies I need to preserve is HttpOnly, which is one of the reasons for the CookieContainer.

> If the server sends HTTPOnly cookies, you should create a
>   System.Net.CookieContainer on the request to hold the cookies,
>   although you will not see or be able to access the cookies that are
>   stored in the container.

So, any ideas?  Am I missing something simple?  Is there another way to save the state of the CookieContainer or do I need to save off the users info including password and re-authentic them every time the app starts and when coming back from tombstoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access private members outside of your assembly in WP7, even with Reflection. It's a security measure put in place to ensure you cannot call internal system APIs.

It looks like you may be out of luck.

Comment: Yeah, you'd think this would be something thats simple to do.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a CookieSerializer that specifically address this issue. The serializer is pasted below. For a working project and scenario, please visit the project's [CodePlex site](http://cookiemanagement.codeplex.com/).

```
public static class CookieSerializer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes the cookie collection to the stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cookies">You can obtain the collection through your <see cref="CookieAwareWebClient">WebClient</see>'s <code>CookieContainer.GetCookies(Uri)</code>-method.</param>
    /// <param name="address">The <see cref="Uri">Uri</see> that produced the cookies</param>
    /// <param name="stream">The stream to which to serialize</param>
    public static void Serialize(CookieCollection cookies, Uri address, Stream stream)
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            for (var enumerator = cookies.GetEnumerator(); enumerator.MoveNext();)
            {
                var cookie = enumerator.Current as Cookie;
                if (cookie == null) continue;
                writer.WriteLine(address.AbsoluteUri);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Comment);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.CommentUri == null ? null : cookie.CommentUri.AbsoluteUri);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Discard);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Domain);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Expired);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Expires);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.HttpOnly);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Name);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Path);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Port);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Secure);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Value);
                writer.WriteLine(cookie.Version);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes <see cref="Cookie">Cookie</see>s from the <see cref="Stream">Stream</see>, 
    /// filling the <see cref="CookieContainer">CookieContainer</see>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">Stream to read</param>
    /// <param name="container">Container to fill</param>
    public static void Deserialize(Stream stream, CookieContainer container)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var uri = Read(reader, absoluteUri => new Uri(absoluteUri, UriKind.Absolute));
                var cookie = new Cookie();
                cookie.Comment = Read(reader, comment => comment);
                cookie.CommentUri = Read(reader, absoluteUri => new Uri(absoluteUri, UriKind.Absolute));
                cookie.Discard = Read(reader, bool.Parse);
                cookie.Domain = Read(reader, domain => domain);
                cookie.Expired = Read(reader, bool.Parse);
                cookie.Expires = Read(reader, DateTime.Parse);
                cookie.HttpOnly = Read(reader, bool.Parse);
                cookie.Name = Read(reader, name => name);
                cookie.Path = Read(reader, path => path);
                cookie.Port = Read(reader, port => port);
                cookie.Secure = Read(reader, bool.Parse);
                cookie.Value = Read(reader, value => value);
                cookie.Version = Read(reader, int.Parse);
                container.Add(uri, cookie);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads a value (line) from the serialized file, translating the string value into a specific type
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Target type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="reader">Input stream</param>
    /// <param name="translator">Translation function - translate the read value into 
    /// <typeparamref name="T"/> if the read value is not <code>null</code>.
    /// <remarks>If the target type is <see cref="Uri">Uri</see> , the value is considered <code>null</code> if it's an empty string.</remarks> </param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value to return if the read value is <code>null</code>.
    /// <remarks>The translation function will not be called for null values.</remarks></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static T Read<T>(TextReader reader, Func<string, T> translator, T defaultValue = default(T))
    {
        var value = reader.ReadLine();
        if (value == null)
            return defaultValue;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Uri) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            return defaultValue;
        return translator(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work with wp7? I didn't think wp7 supported HTTPOnly cookies.

Comment: HTTPOnly cookies will be present but it will be hidden even you wont be able to read from code. What you can do: You can reassign the same CookieContainer again and again with next all subsequent requests.